# Switch button text back and forth with Bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button I'm using with bootstrap.

I'd like to flip the text back and forth with each click. So for example the button' default text would be "Off", you click it, it now shows "On".  Click it again and it's "Off" again and so on.
Below is my bootrap and jquery code.  How would I change this to meet my needs?

```
<button type="button"  id="cmdLargeButton" data-complete-text="On" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" autocomplete="off">Off</button>
 <script>
      $('#cmdLargeButton').on('click', function () {
          $(this).button('complete')
      })
</script>
```

Also, I can't figure out whey I'm getting this error using the "autocomplete" parameter which the example I saw said I had to use.  Not sure what it does.  Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

[image: Autocomplete error]

Comment: Interested to know why my question had a negative vote?  I figured any question is a good question. 
And I apologize.  I thought I did accept the answer as what I was looking for.  My checkmark didn't take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator with condition check and the two texts that you want to swap on each click

Working snippet:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#cmdLargeButton').on('click', function () {
      $(this).text($(this).text() == "Off" ? "On" : "Off");
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"  id="cmdLargeButton" data-complete-text="On" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" autocomplete="off">Off</button>
```