# Button to change text back and forth JS

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I am trying to make a button that changes temperature to Fahrenheit on click, but if it is clicked again, changes the temperature back to Celsius. If you click the temperature symbol(i.e Celsius) it should change the temperature to Fahrenheit. If the Fahrenheit symbol, it should show the temperature in Celsius again.

The problem is that my current button changed the temperature to Fahrenheit and immediately changes it back to Celsius.

In my research, I found the `toggle()` jquery function, but it seems that it is now deprecated and, to be honest, I don't really understand how to use it.n

I also found this stackoverflow qustion, but do not know how to apply the answer to my situation: [Switch button text back and forth with Bootstrap and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326337/switch-button-text-back-and-forth-with-bootstrap-and-jquery)

Thanks!

```
var currentTemp= "cel";
  $("#tempUnit").click(function(){

  alert("Temperature Changed to Fahrenheit.");
//   var currentTemp= cel;
    if (currentTemp=== "cel") {
    currentTemp = "faren"; 
      var farCalc=  (data.main.temp * 1.8) + 32;

   $('#temp').html("Temperature:" + Math.round(farCalc) +"");
     $('#tempUnit').html("&#8457");
   }
    if (currentTemp=== "faren"){

  alert("Temperature Changed to Celsius");
   $('#temp').html("Temperature:" + data.main.temp +"");
     $('#tempUnit').html("&#8451");  
      }
```

See full code here: https://codepen.io/mso122591/pen/XZZWPR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that my current button changed the temperature to Fahrenheit and immediately changes it back to Celsius.

This happens because you are setting `currentTemp = "faren"` in the condition `if (currentTemp=== "cel")` which return to true for the first time and then you are again using `if` condition instead you should use else block like this

```js
var currentTemp = "cel";
$("#tempUnit").click(function() {

      alert("Temperature Changed to Fahrenheit.");
      //   var currentTemp= cel;
      if (currentTemp === "cel") {
        currentTemp = "faren";
        var farCalc = (data.main.temp * 1.8) + 32;

        $('#temp').html("Temperature:" + Math.round(farCalc) + "");
        $('#tempUnit').html("&#8457");
      }
      else {
         currentTemp = "cel";
        alert("Temperature Changed to Celsius");
        $('#temp').html("Temperature:" + data.main.temp + "");
        $('#tempUnit').html("&#8451");
      }
```

**P.S** Again set `currentTemp = "cel";` in else block

Answer (score 0):

First off the codepen looks broken and honestly extremely difficult to read. I gave up before trying. So I'm will answer in a way that describes how I would approach the problem.

First break up your responsibilities into different functions. Then connect those functions together. You will be managing state (in this case which degree your currently on. And finally attaching to the DOM with the results and the event handler for when the user clicks. Each is it's own self contained function.

```js
$(function() {

var TEMP_SYMBOLS = {
  celceus: '&#8451',
  fahrenheit: '&#8457'
};

var TEMP_CONVERTERS = {
  celceus: function(temp) { return temp; },
  fahrenheit: function(temp) { return (temp * 1.8) + 32; }
};

var currentTemp = 0;
var currentTempMode = 'celceus';

function fetchTemp() {
  // Here is where you fetch the temp from AJAX.
  // For demonstration purposes we will simply hard code a value.
  currentTemp = 32.4;
}

function renderTemp() {
  var symbol = TEMP_SYMBOLS[currentTempMode];
  var converter = TEMP_CONVERTERS[currentTempMode];
  var value = converter(currentTemp);
  $('#temp-output').html('Temperature: ' + value + ' ' + symbol);
}

fetchTemp();
renderTemp();

$('#temp-output').on('click', function() {
  currentTempMode = currentTempMode === 'celceus' ? 'fahrenheit' : 'celceus';
  renderTemp();
});

});
```

```css
#temp-output {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="temp-output">Loading&hellip;</span>
```